# Using a displaylink adapter with the Xorg modesetting driver

Tags: linux, xorg, display-driver

I have a USB2 displaylink adapter connected to my machine so as to make use of that nice second monitor I have here.  The primary graphics card is the dreaded Poulsbo, so there's no hardware acceleration to worry about (makes no difference in Emacs anyway ;-).

So I'm using a trivial xorg.conf with just:

```
Section "Device"
    Identifier      "Video Device"
    driver          "modesetting"
EndSection
```

The X server starts up OK but only the main (i.e. Poulsbo-connected) display gets used.  The other card is detected (as evidenced by "xrandr --list-providers" output), but "not enough" (as evidenced by the fact that only one output shows up in "xrandr"):

```
% xrandr
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 1200 x 1600, maximum 4096 x 4096
DVI-0 connected 1200x1600+0+0 left (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 432mm x 324mm
   1600x1200     60.00*+  54.88  
   1280x1024     75.02    60.02  
   1280x960      60.00  
   1152x864      75.00  
   1024x768      75.08    70.07    60.00  
   832x624       74.55  
   800x600       72.19    75.00    60.32    56.25  
   640x480       75.00    72.81    66.67    60.00  
   720x400       70.08  
% xrandr --listproviders
Providers: number : 2
Provider 0: id: 0x77 cap: 0x0 crtcs: 2 outputs: 1 associated providers: 0 name:modesetting
Provider 1: id: 0x41 cap: 0x2, Sink Output crtcs: 1 outputs: 1 associated providers: 0 name:modesetting
%
```

The Xorg.0.log file doesn't have any special (WW) or (EE), except for the expected glamor/aiglx failures.  The only other hint of possible problem I see is when I start "xinit" I get:

```
pci id for fd 10: 8086:8108, driver (null)
EGL_MESA_drm_image required.
MESA-LOADER: malformed or no PCI ID
gbm: failed to open any driver (search paths /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/dri:${ORIGIN}/dri:/usr/lib/dri)
gbm: Last dlopen error: /usr/lib/dri/udl_dri.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
failed to load driver: udl
EGL_MESA_drm_image required.
xf86: found device 1
```

So my question is: how can I enable the output on my second (displaylink) card?  Or alternatively, where can I find further info (since web-searches lead me nowhere because the "modesetting" keyword ends up matching lots of irrelevant threads about other drivers)?

Answer (score 0):

The new DisplayLink driver (udldrmfb) piggy backs off your graphics card, in my case, I wish to use the Intel DRI/OpenGL, yet use USB for display. udlfb is old and should be blacklisted. fbdev doesn't give you hardware acceleration.

**Out of the box, if plugged in before boot, my screen works with no xorg.conf**

```
xrandr --listproviders
Provider 0: id: 0x48 cap: 0x9, Source Output, Sink Offload crtcs: 4 outputs: 5 associated providers: 1 name:Intel
Provider 1: id: 0xe8 cap: 0x2, Sink Output crtcs: 1 outputs: 1 associated providers: 1 name:modesetting
```

However, I wanted a working Xorg.conf so I could tweak / use with Mali (ARM) on an Odroid, which requires a Xorg.conf

`BusID` and `kmsdev` will need tweaking for your particular setup, see `lspci` and `/sys/class/drm/`. The Monitor section can be omitted if your monitor has a proper EDID.

```
Section "Device"
    Identifier  "inteldev"
    Driver      "intel"
    BusID       "PCI:0:2:0"
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier  "usbdev"
    Driver      "modesetting"
    Option      "kmsdev" "/dev/dri/card0"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
    Identifier "DVI-1-0"
    Option "PreferredMode" "1280x800"
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier     "Screen0"
    Device         "inteldev"
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier     "Screen1"
    Device         "usbdev"
EndSection

Section "ServerLayout"
    Identifier     "Layout0"
    Screen      0  "Screen0" 0 0
    Screen      1  "Screen1"
    Option         "Xinerama" "0"
EndSection
```

Environment:
Ubuntu 14.04.1, 3.19.0-9-generic kernel, Intel i7-4770R, Iris Pro 5200, Mimo USB screen.

Comment: We need two device sections, so each driver knows what hardware to control. In order to load a driver, you need a screen. Screens are only active if configured in a server layout.

Comment: Could you explain how's that relevant to my question (where both graphics cards should be managed by the modesetting driver)?

Comment: In my testing, DisplayLink display would NOT work with both providers being modesetting (eg: Modesetting being used for Intel). Intel had to use a real driver. So I infer, what your attempting, may be impossible.

Comment: Try using my Xorg.conf, and setting the "inteldev" device also to modesetting. Maybe it will work with your setup. "Trivial Xorg.conf" from OP is too minimal to get drivers to load correctly for the correct hardware.